# What is a good troubleshooting methodology for an unmanaged switch causing connection drop-offs?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, wired-networking

I have added an unmanaged switch [device link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076PRM2C5) to my home network to provide wired connections to two devices in another room (MacBook Pro and an Xbox One). Since adding the switch I have had repeated connection losses (upwards of 10 times a day) for the two devices wired to the switch, which is always immediately solved by disconnecting and reconnecting the ethernet cable (either on device end or switch end).

I'm struggling to think of trouble shooting methods since the switch is unmanaged (no settings to change) and the drop-offs are happening on two devices (this likely eliminated cable issues as the culprit).

I have examined my router's description of the network and see no conflicting IP addressed and have gone as far as to add both devices as static IPs to make sure of that. Also I have made sure that the wireless capabilities of both devices are turned off to prevent any interface issues.

I don't see this being a power issue since replugging the ethernet of a device solves the issue, though there may be something i am overlooking about POE (even though neither device is using the POE capability?).

I am also unsure if one of the devices connection settings could be causing the issues for both devices?

Is there a troubleshooting methodology used in a professional environment that could help me identify what is causing these drop offs and resolve the issue before I try to replace the device itself?

Comment: I usually try a substitute Switch. If you can take the switch out and the remaining connections work fine, it is probably the switch. If new have it replaced under warranty.

Comment: @John yeah, thats about where i am at, unfortunately i have no spare switches on hand. So i just wanted to check if there were any glaring troubleshooting holes in my methodology so far before i go through with asking for a replacement, as i rarely find that hardware is at fault in my experience